# C# Selenium - Detecting successful login

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I asked a question earlier about logging in to a website using Selenium in C# but now I'm encountering an issue where the program crashes on an un-successful login, giving the reason that key was not found. I've got a try + catch (exception) included but it skips it.

My question is how can I detect whether a login was successful or not? And if it is unsuccessful if it's possible to exit out of the login form and carry on with the tests.

My code for the method is here:

```
private static void LogInAsUser()
    {
        try
        {
            Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[contains(@href, '#login-window')]")).Click();

            Thread.Sleep(500);

            IWebElement username = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@id, 'UserName')]"));
            IWebElement password = Driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[contains(@id, 'Password')]"));

            username.Clear();
            username.SendKeys("user@exampleemail.com");

            password.Clear();
            password.SendKeys("examplepass");

            Driver.FindElement(By.Id("btnLogin")).Click();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }

    }
```

And my call method (incase it makes any difference) is:

```
//Log in as User
        try
        {
            LogInAsUser();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Result.Fail(60);
        }
```

As well as the HTML for the error message upon unsuccessful login

```
<div id="msgError" class="col-md-12 text-center">Login failed: The user name or password provided is incorrect.</div>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looking at your login method you're not actually looking at the result.
Where in your code does it look for the msgError element? The catch I see would be catching ElementNotFoundException, for username and password fields if they weren't on the page, but that isn't tied to an unsuccessful login

Comment: Maybe adding details of the exception you are getting might help

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a suggestion on how to detect a successful login. What I have done is to look for a few elements that will be present after you login. Once those elements are successfully located, you will know this log in is good.

For example, in my test cases, I will be looking for the "title" element of the page right after log in. Also, to be sure, I also try to locate the element that is an image.

About catching that exception, have you tried to press F12 to access Console massage? You might be able to catch a message there.